# cocos2d Children sprite collision detection with parent sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parent, collision-detection, sprite

Hi stackoverflow community!

How do you detect a children sprite collision with a parent sprite in cocos2d?

Currently I have my codes like this:

```
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

    parentJumper = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"inviBtn.png"];
    jumper = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumperRight.png"];

    plat = [[Platform alloc]init];

    plat = [Platform spriteWithFile:@"platformBlack.png"];

    plat.position = ccp(160,100);

    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(1.0/60)];

    jumper.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0);
    jumper.position = ccp(0, 20);
    parentJumper.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, 0);

    [self addChild:plat];
    [self addChild:parentJumper];
    [parentJumper addChild:jumper];
```

Now how do I detect the collision between "**jumper**" & "**plat**"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: first of all, why you init your plat two times? you will get memory leak here. the second you can translate rect coordinates of compared sprites to world coordinates then compare them

Answer (score -1):

Usually you can check collision like this:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect([jumper boundingBox], [plat boundingBox])) {
  //Handle collision<br>
}
```